# Structuring a Rails app with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Simple question,

in rails App, made a scaffold

```
rails g scaffold Post title:string body:string
```

i want to add simple condition in front-end javascript

if the @posts exists, `alert("exist")`
else, `alert("no posts")`

I can add this scripts `inside views/posts/index.html.erb`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        if (<%=@posts.length%> > 2)
            alert("exist");
        else
            alert("no posts");
    });
</script>

<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

the problem is,

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        if (<%=@posts.length%> > 2)
            alert("exist");
        else
            alert("no posts");
    });
</script>
```

i want to seprated this to an individual js file.

so, i have put this code in

```
assets/javascripts/posts.js

  $(function () {
            if (<%=@posts.length%> > 2)
                alert("exist");
            else
                alert("no posts");
  });
```

but in here, it cannot use <%=%> this rails view stuff :(

Is there are good solution?

Comment: oh the possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data attribute to your table with post count, and perhaps a class to only listen on certain pages. Something like:

```
# view
body class=controller_name
  table data-posts-count=@posts.length
```

.

```
# js
$("body.posts").load(function() {
  count = $(this).data("posts-count")

  if count > 2
    alert("exist");
  else
    alert("no posts");
});
```